# Email SMTP validator in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I need to send hundreds of newsletters, but would like to check first if email exists on server.

any body please send solution

here is my smtp validation code, i can run can this code it's takes too much time to validate an email

```
require_once('smtp_validateEmail.php');

$email = 'example1@gmail.com';
$sender = 'example.gmail.com';
$SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_Validate_Email();

$SMTP_Validator->debug = true;

$results = $SMTP_Validator->validate(array($email), $sender);
echo $results[$email];
```

Comment: What does you mean **email exists on server** ?

Comment: You can run a cron job that will clean all the emails from database. Then send the emails without validating if they exist on server. And you can use validation at time of saving emails for future emails